# PHP Include with a twist

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an include

```
include ('myfile.php');
```

Now, I am using wordpress and to get the template path I use:

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

My question is:

How can I use both together?

Like:

```
<?php

include('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/myfile.php');

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
include(get_template_directory_uri() . "/myfile.php");
```

The [`include()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) just takes a string parameter.  Nothing special about it.

Comment: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0

Answer (score 2):

You can use the result of the function in the include, but not by echo:ing it. Just use it directly.

```
<?php
include(get_template_directory_uri() . '/myfile.php');
```